# MPU 9250 does not show data

Tags: arduino, esp32, arduino-esp32

I have this code for Arduino ID, I am doing it with an ESP 32 and an MPU 9250/6500 sensor, the problem is that when executing instead of displaying the data, it sends me an error, any suggestions?

The wiring is fine, and devices used too, the problem is in the code that does not show the values.

For some reason it worked for a moment, showing data, but it caused a reboot on my PC, when I started all my code was lost and now it doesn't show data.

`#include "MPU9250.h"
  #include <Wire.h>

  // Define a different I2C bus as MainWire
  TwoWire MainWire = TwoWire(0);

  // an MPU9250 object with the MPU-9250 sensor on the custom I2C bus (MainWire) with address 0x68
  MPU9250 IMU = MPU9250(MainWire, 0x68);

  int status;

  void setup() {
  // serial to display data
  delay(6000);
  Serial.begin(115200);
  while(!Serial) {}

  // initialize the custom I2C bus
  MainWire.begin(21, 22);

  // start communication with IMU 
  status = IMU.begin();
  if (status < 0) {
    Serial.println("IMU initialization unsuccessful");
    Serial.println("Check IMU wiring or try cycling power");
    Serial.print("Status: ");
    Serial.println(status);
    while(1) {}
  }
  // setting the accelerometer full scale range to +/-8G 
  IMU.setAccelRange(MPU9250::ACCEL_RANGE_8G);
  // setting the gyroscope full scale range to +/-500 deg/s
  IMU.setGyroRange(MPU9250::GYRO_RANGE_500DPS);
  // setting DLPF bandwidth to 20 Hz
  IMU.setDlpfBandwidth(MPU9250::DLPF_BANDWIDTH_20HZ);
  // setting SRD to 19 for a 50 Hz update rate
  IMU.setSrd(19);
}

void loop() {
  // read the sensor
  IMU.readSensor();

  // display the data
  Serial.print(IMU.getAccelX_mss(), 6);
  Serial.print("\t");
  Serial.print(IMU.getAccelY_mss(), 6);
  Serial.print("\t");
  Serial.print(IMU.getAccelZ_mss(), 6);
  Serial.print("\t");
  Serial.print(IMU.getGyroX_rads(), 6);
  Serial.print("\t");
  Serial.print(IMU.getGyroY_rads(), 6);
  Serial.print("\t");
  Serial.print(IMU.getGyroZ_rads(), 6);
  Serial.print("\t");
  Serial.print(IMU.getMagX_uT(), 6);
  Serial.print("\t");
  Serial.print(IMU.getMagY_uT(), 6);
  Serial.print("\t");
  Serial.print(IMU.getMagZ_uT(), 6);
  Serial.print("\t");
  Serial.println(IMU.getTemperature_C(), 6);
  delay(1000);
}`

First I tried without using the wire library, and without initializing pins 21 and 22, but when I executed nothing happened. I tried trying the above and now it shows an error, which I don't know why, but for a moment it worked that way. Also, I don't know why, if I don't put a delay before the serial begin, it doesn't even show the error in the console.